# How to Mock FeatureFilterEvaluationContext Parameters?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, feature-flags, azure-feature-manager

I created a custom feature filter and in EvaluateAsync I get the feature flag's custom settings from Azure's Feature manager for this specific feature flag's filter.

```
public virtual Task<Boolean> EvaluateAsync(FeatureFilterEvaluationContext context)
{
    _settings = context.Parameters.Get<IdFilterSettings>();
```

Where IdFilterSettings looks like this:

```
internal class IdFilterSettings
{
    public String[]? AllowedIds { get; set; }
    public String[]? BlockedIds { get; set; }
}
```

When calling it through an actual API call, `_settings` properly gets set to a new instance of `IdFilterSettings` with `AllowedIds` and `BlockedIds` properly populated.

But, when I try to unit test this and mock `FeatureFilterEvaluationContext` with this code:

```
var allowedIds = new string[2] { "someId1", "someId2" };
var blockedIds = new string[1] { "someId3" };
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string?>
{
    { "AllowedIds", JsonSerializer.Serialize(allowedIds) },
    { "BlockedIds", JsonSerializer.Serialize(blockedIds) }
};
var context = new FeatureFilterEvaluationContext
{
    Parameters = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddInMemoryCollection(parameters).Build()
};

_filter = new CustomIdFilter(_httpContextAccessor.Object);

var result = await _filter.EvaluateAsync(context);
```

If I put a break point after `_settings = context.Parameters.Get<IdFilterSettings>();`, settings is a new instance of `IdFilterSettings`, but `AllowedIds` and `BlockedIds` are both null.

Answer (score 2):

As per jimmyca15's answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/FeatureManagement-Dotnet/issues/231), I had to alter the parameters Dictionary to be:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string?>
{
    { "AllowedIds:0", "someId1" },
    { "AllowedIds:1", "someId2" },
    { "BlockedIds:0", "someId3" }
};
```

Comment: Can I just say that I hate this :/